# How can I detect if the URL is contain word after a fixed URL?

Tags: javascript

I have following URL

http://test.mysite.com/#inbox

Now I want to show alert message if any word exist after `/#inbox` like

http://test.mysite.com/#inbox/CXPhOilToWCgCYe

You can see that after `/#inbox` I have string. Now I want to show JavaScript alert() message.

How can I detect if the URL contain any word after the `/#inbox`?

I can show the alert message:

```
alert('Some String');
```

Comment: `window.location.hash.split('/')[1]` This might help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to extract the part after the required string, can do it using substr method

```
var url = "http://test.mysite.com/#inbox/CXPhOilToWCgCYe";
var extracted = url.substr(url.indexOf("#inbox") + "#inbox".length);
var isPresent = (extracted.indexOf("yourword") > -1 ? true : false);
```

Comment: I just noticed that the code you did is must be match the exact word but I want to detect any word, can you do this?

Comment: yes, you can try var isPresent = extracted.length > 0 if I understood your requirement correctly

Comment: let me try it now.

Comment: @creativeartbd have you consider my answer? you don't need to find the length of the words

Answer (score 0):

You can split the URL and check whether it's containing some string after inbox/ or not

```js
var url = "http://test.mysite.com/#inbox/CXPhOilToWCgCYe";
var split = url.split('#inbox');

console.log("splited url", split[1])
//you can show alert accordingly 
if (split[1]) {
  alert('some string')
}
var url = "http://test.mysite.com/#inbox";
var split = url.split('#inbox');

console.log("splited url", split[1])
//here popup will not show
if (split[1]) {
  alert('some string')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use string functions

```
function myFunction() {
  var str = "http://test.mysite.com/#inbox/CXPhOilToWCgCYe";
  var n = str.indexOf("#inbox");

 alert(str.substring(n+7, str.length));
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mur19kd4/